# How to preallocate VideoWriter file in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, video, pre-allocation

My code generates 10 videos in a for loop using the `VideoWriter` function. I know how to pre-allocate arrays but I am not sure how to make pre-allocation for VideoWriter files. writerObj file in the code below should be pre-allocated.

```
for i=1:10
 
     images  = cell(28,1);
    writerObj(i) = VideoWriter(sprintf('bc_e2_ld_e5_time_history1/%d.avi',i));
    writerObj(i).FrameRate = 1;   % create the video writer with 1 fps
    secsPerImage = ones(1,28);  % set the seconds per image
    open(writerObj(i));   % open the video writer
    
 %-----------------------------Save images for making videos ---------------   
    
     for j=1:28
        h=figure('visible','off');    
        p = pcolor(intrpVMStress1(:,:,j));
        p.EdgeColor='none';
        set(gca,'visible','off')
        colormap('jet');
%       colorbar;
        axis equal;
        title 'Von Mises Stress';
        saveas(h,sprintf('bc_e2_ld_e5_time_history1/FIG%d.jpg',j));  % save the images
        images{j}=imread(sprintf('bc_e2_ld_e5_time_history1/FIG%d.jpg',j)); % load the images
     end 
     
%-----------------------------convert the image to a frame ---------------    
      for u=1:length(images)
            % convert the image to a frame
          frame = im2frame(images{u});
                 for v=1:secsPerImage(u) 
                     writeVideo(writerObj(i), frame);
                 end
      end
 close(writerObj(i)); 
    
end
```

Comment: You only access `writerObj(i)` inside the loop. You create it, write to it, and close it. Why keep all the others around? You don’t need to make this into a matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "Why keep all the others around?" ?

Comment: Is there any suggestion to speed up the code?

Comment: Instead of `writerObj(i)`, just write `writerObj`. But this is not going to make a noticeable difference in execution time. Writing movie files takes time.

Comment: You can speed up the code by not doing figure -> file -> matrix -> frame, but directly figure -> frame. Use `getframe`. In the loop over j, do `writeVideo(writerObj, getframe(gcf))`, then skip that second loop.